# I want to use a while loop to start with a starting value and multiply by 3 until it reaches 20,000. More specfied below

Tags: loops, while-loop

***In this you will figure out how many generations it will take for a start value of bunnies to reach 20,000. Where every pair of bunnies has 3 bunnies each time through.***
**In java language**
Examples:

Start = 10  (with 10 bunnies)
Return = 9  (Number of generations)

Start = 20  (with 20 bunnies)
Return = 8  (Number of generations)

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: int i=0;
     String words= ""; 

     while(int i = 0; i <= word.length(5); i++)
     {
           if(word.charAt(i) == ' ')
       {
             words= word.substring(0, i);

Comment: This doesn't seem a valid code (mismatched `for` syntax with a `while` keyword, unpaired curly braces, a numeric parameter to the `length()` method...), let alone completeness. It's also unclear to me what is the connection with a multiplying bunnies problem (a `String words` variable? a reference to undefined `word` variable`?...) At least it indicates you're working with the C or, more probably, C++ language. Or Java...

Comment: Yes I know that's what i need help with. I'm still a beginner in JAVA.

Comment: The problem is incomplete. What is a 'generation'? A lifespan of a single animal, a time needed to mature or a period of consecutive multiplications? It's unclear also how long it takes the newborns to mature – is the time equal to the multiplication period? IRL it's not, and appropriate anaysis yields Fibonacci numbers of bunnies! What is a distribution of sex - how do we know there is always equal number of males and females? Etc, etc, etc...

Comment: Okay. Forget about the last code. Here is what i'm trying to do.     10 will make 5 pairs.  5 pairs will make 15 offsprings (since it's 5*3). For the first generation it's 10+15=25 which will make 12 pairs with will make 36 offsprings. For the second generation its 25+36=71  and so on until it reaches 20,000> How many generations did it take me. (The time and lifespan are not a part of this program.)

Comment: Okay. Forget about the last code. Here is what i'm trying to do. 10 will make 5 pairs. 5 pairs will make 15 offsprings (since it's 5*3). For the first generation it's 10+15=25 which will make 12 pairs with will make 36 offsprings. For the second generation its 25+36=71 and so on until it reaches 20,000> How many generations did it take me. (The time and lifespan are not a part of this program.)  @CiaPan

Answer (score 0):

This answer is presented in PSEUDO-CODE since you haven't specified the programming language in use. So here you have:

```
....

Generations = 0

MyCounter = 7 /* This is my starting value */
WHILE (MyCounter <= 20000)
LOOP

  [do something]

  Generations = Generations + 1

  MyCounter = MyCounter * 3 

END LOOP ;

PRINT Generations 
....
```

Comment: Sorry about that. In java.

Comment: OK, you can translate my PSEUDO-CODE to JAVA (I assume you can manage, right?).

Comment: I will try but I only know JAVA.

Comment: If my answer (its logic) is what you were looking for, then: (1) knowing JAVA is all you need (extremely simple code) and (2) you may wish to up-vote my answer and mark it as such by clicking on the "V".

Comment: Okay. Forget about the last code. Here is what i'm trying to do. 10 will make 5 pairs. 5 pairs will make 15 offsprings (since it's 5*3). For the first generation it's 10+15=25 which will make 12 pairs with will make 36 offsprings. For the second generation its 25+36=71 and so on until it reaches 20,000> How many generations did it take me. (The time and lifespan are not a part of this program.)

Comment: I suggest you either create a new question or re-phrase this one with a detailed description of the algorithm. In the meantime, I believe I answered your original question even is it was wrongly phrased).